# Magento 2: How to check that customer is logged in on frontend?

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

**Checkout Minicart content.html**

```
<div class="block-content">
    <button type="button"
            id="btn-minicart-close"
            class="action close"
            data-action="close"
            data-bind="attr: { title: $t('Close') }">
        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Close' --><!-- /ko --></span>
    </button>

    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
    <div class="items-total">
        <span class="count"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') == 1 -->
        <!-- ko i18n: 'item' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') > 1 -->
        <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>

    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('possible_onepage_checkout') -->
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('subtotalContainer') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('extraInfo') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('possible_onepage_checkout') -->
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="primary">
            <!-- ko if: customer().firstname -->
                <a id="top-cart-btn-checkout"
                   class="action primary checkout"
                   href="#">
                    <!-- ko i18n: 'Go to Checkout' --><!-- /ko -->
                </a>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <div data-bind="html: getCartParam('extra_actions')"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Recently added item(s)' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
    <div data-action="scroll" class="minicart-items-wrapper">
        <ol id="mini-cart" class="minicart-items" data-bind="foreach: { data: getCartParam('items'), as: 'item' }">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type)) -->
            <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item, afterRender: function() {$parents[1].initSidebar()}} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </ol>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
    <strong class="subtitle empty" data-bind="visible: closeSidebar()">
        <!-- ko i18n: 'You have no items in your shopping cart.' --><!-- /ko -->
    </strong>
    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('cart_empty_message') -->
    <p class="minicart empty text"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('cart_empty_message') --><!-- /ko --></p>

    <div class="actions">
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
                <span><!-- ko text: $t('View and edit cart') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action viewcart cartAction" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
                <span class="viewcartBtnWrapper"><!-- ko i18n: 'View and edit cart' --><!-- /ko --></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <div id="minicart-widgets" class="minicart-widgets">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('promotion') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "customer": {
                    "component": "Magento_Customer/js/model/customer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**Error**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return getCartParam('summary_count') }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return getCartParam('possible_onepage_checkout') }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return customer().firstname }"
Message: customer is not defined
    at if (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.min.js:268), <anonymous>:3:55)
    at ko.computed.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.min.js:365)
    at evaluateImmediate (knockout.min.js:183)
    at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.min.js:204)
    at init (knockout.min.js:365)
    at knockout.min.js:300
    at Object.ignore (knockout.min.js:129)
    at knockout.min.js:300
    at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.min.js:17)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.min.js:299)
```

Please let me know how can I check the customer is login or not by knockout js HTML page?

Comment: if you get `<!-- ko if: customer().firstname -->` firstname it means you are logged in.

Comment: Not getting <!-- ko if: customer().firstname --> got the error in console @RakeshVarma

Comment: Please let me know what the issue in above code? @RakeshVarma

Comment: can you please post the error

Comment: Please check the error in post @RakeshVarma

Comment: please post your whole file code. I think something is missing

Comment: Please check @RakeshVarma

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101078/discussion-between-masud-shaikh-and-rakesh-varma).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create `default.xml` file here in your module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <referenceBlock name="minicart">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/minicart/content</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now you need to create `content.html` file here on this path

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html

You can copy content of this default Vendor file there and comment button code

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html

If you want to add condition in that button then you need to create one `requirejs-config.js` file here on this location in your custom module..

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

Content for this file is..

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/view/minicart-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now create one `minicart-mixin.js` file here on this location

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart-mixin.js

Content for this file is..

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'sidebar',
    'mage/translate'
], function (Component, customerData, $, ko) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        isCustomerLoggedIn: function () {
            var customer = customerData.get('customer');
            if(customer().firstname){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

- Here in this `JS` file I've added **isCustomerLoggedIn()** function there you can add your condition here based on your requirement to show hide your button.

And you can add condition in your `content.html` file like this

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html

Content for this file is..

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="block-title">
    <strong>
        <span class="text"><!-- ko i18n: 'My Cart' --><!-- /ko --></span>
        <span
            class="qty empty"
            data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false },
                       attr: { title: $t('Items in Cart') }">
            <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
        </span>
    </strong>
</div>

<div class="block-content">
    <button type="button"
            id="btn-minicart-close"
            class="action close"
            data-action="close"
            data-bind="attr: { title: $t('Close') }">
        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Close' --><!-- /ko --></span>
    </button>

    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
        <div class="items-total">
            <span class="count"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') == 1 -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'item' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') > 1 -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>

        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('possible_onepage_checkout') -->
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('subtotalContainer') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('extraInfo') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('possible_onepage_checkout') -->
        <div class="actions">
            <div class="primary">
                <!-- ko if: (isCustomerLoggedIn()) -->
                    <button
                            id="top-cart-btn-checkout"
                            type="button"
                            class="action primary checkout"
                            data-action="close"
                            data-bind="
                                attr: {
                                    title: $t('Proceed to Checkout (Logged In)')
                                },
                                click: closeMinicart()
                            "
                            translate="'Proceed to Checkout (Logged In)'"
                    />
                <!--/ko-->

                <!-- ko ifnot: (isCustomerLoggedIn()) -->
                    <button
                            id="top-cart-btn-checkout"
                            type="button"
                            class="action primary checkout"
                            data-action="close"
                            data-bind="
                                attr: {
                                    title: $t('Proceed to Checkout (Not Logged In)')
                                },
                                click: closeMinicart()
                            "
                            translate="'Proceed to Checkout (Not Logged In)'"
                    />
                <!--/ko-->
                <div data-bind="html: getCartParam('extra_actions')"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Recently added item(s)' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
    <div data-action="scroll" class="minicart-items-wrapper">
        <ol id="mini-cart" class="minicart-items" data-bind="foreach: { data: getCartParam('items'), as: 'item' }">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type)) -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item, afterRender: function() {$parents[1].initSidebar()}} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </ol>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
        <strong class="subtitle empty" data-bind="visible: closeSidebar()">
            <!-- ko i18n: 'You have no items in your shopping cart.' --><!-- /ko -->
        </strong>
        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('cart_empty_message') -->
            <p class="minicart empty text"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('cart_empty_message') --><!-- /ko --></p>

            <div class="actions">
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
                        <span><!-- ko text: $t('View and edit cart') --><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
                <span><!-- ko i18n: 'View and edit cart' --><!-- /ko --></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <div id="minicart-widgets" class="minicart-widgets">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('promotion') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('sign-in-popup') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if it helps.

Comment: It is worked. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome buddy. :)

Answer (score 5):

create js file and check using below code

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'
], function (
    Component,
    customer
) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'CustomModule/custom-file'
        },

        /**
         * Customer is logged in
         *
         * @return {boolean}
         */
        isLoggedIn: function () {
            return customer.isLoggedIn();
        }
    });
});
```

check this in custom-file.html

```
<!-- ko if: isLoggedIn() -->
    <div>Customer is logged in</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: I will check and update you. Thanks!

Comment: yes please,  thanks

Comment: Got the console error: Message: isLoggedIn is not defined

Answer (score 1):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
  //your code
}
```

we can easily use it in phtml file

Comment: I want to check in content.html checkout page

Comment: you can use this code and use it in any phtml

Comment: It is not usable for me.

Comment: can you show me the part of your code

Comment: I have posted my code above and my issue is resolved. Thanks for your help

Comment: most welcome @MasudShaikh

Comment: If You liked my answer please vote Up Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try this. I have added new `<div data-bind="scope:'customer'">` to define scope of your js component.

```
<div data-bind="scope:'customer'">
<div class="block-content">
   <button type="button"
      id="btn-minicart-close"
      class="action close"
      data-action="close"
      data-bind="attr: { title: $t('Close') }">
      <span>
         <!-- ko i18n: 'Close' --><!-- /ko -->
      </span>
   </button>
   <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
   <div class="items-total">
      <span class="count">
         <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
      </span>
      <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') == 1 -->
      <!-- ko i18n: 'item' --><!-- /ko -->
      <!-- /ko -->
      <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') > 1 -->
      <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
      <!-- /ko -->
   </div>
   <!-- ko if: getCartParam('possible_onepage_checkout') -->
   <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('subtotalContainer') -->
   <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
   <!-- /ko -->
   <!-- /ko -->
   <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('extraInfo') -->
   <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
   <!-- /ko -->
   <!-- ko if: getCartParam('possible_onepage_checkout') -->
   <div class="actions">
      <div class="primary">
         <!-- ko if: customer().firstname -->
         <a id="top-cart-btn-checkout"
            class="action primary checkout"
            href="#">
            <!-- ko i18n: 'Go to Checkout' --><!-- /ko -->
         </a>
         <!-- /ko -->
         <div data-bind="html: getCartParam('extra_actions')"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- /ko -->
   <!-- /ko -->
   <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
   <strong class="subtitle">
      <!-- ko i18n: 'Recently added item(s)' --><!-- /ko -->
   </strong>
   <div data-action="scroll" class="minicart-items-wrapper">
      <ol id="mini-cart" class="minicart-items" data-bind="foreach: { data: getCartParam('items'), as: 'item' }">
         <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type)) -->
         <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item, afterRender: function() {$parents[1].initSidebar()}} --><!-- /ko -->
         <!-- /ko -->
      </ol>
   </div>
   <!-- /ko -->
   <!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
   <strong class="subtitle empty" data-bind="visible: closeSidebar()">
      <!-- ko i18n: 'You have no items in your shopping cart.' --><!-- /ko -->
   </strong>
   <!-- ko if: getCartParam('cart_empty_message') -->
   <p class="minicart empty text">
      <!-- ko text: getCartParam('cart_empty_message') --><!-- /ko -->
   </p>
   <div class="actions">
      <div class="secondary">
         <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
            <span>
               <!-- ko text: $t('View and edit cart') --><!-- /ko -->
            </span>
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- /ko -->
   <!-- /ko -->
   <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
   <div class="actions">
      <div class="secondary">
         <a class="action viewcart cartAction" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
            <span class="viewcartBtnWrapper">
               <!-- ko i18n: 'View and edit cart' --><!-- /ko -->
            </span>
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- /ko -->
   <div id="minicart-widgets" class="minicart-widgets">
      <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('promotion') -->
      <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
      <!-- /ko -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Div is not closed.

Comment: updated answer with closing div. Is it working?

Comment: I have got the error. Please check the message in chatroom.

Comment: why down vote??

Comment: I have not downed vote.

Comment: Okay.. let me know if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: Proceed to checkout: if Customer is login redirect to checkout. if Customer is not login redirect to custom page.

Comment: if possible upload your extension in git so I can check whole code.

Comment: My issue is resolved. Thanks for your hep.